# What is my C# MVC Web app api's URI?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, api, controller

I've spent over a day just trying to get the jquery of my home page, to hit an api controller I have in my C# ASP.NET MVC project.

The RouteConfig.cs in APP_START is as such:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "API Default",
            url: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );


    }
```

My class in called LogInController and is in the Controllers directory:
[image: Project Structure]

I've got the LogInController class set up as such:
[image: LogInController Structure]

Here is my jquery on Index.cshtml:

```
var apiUrl = "api/LogIn";
```

-

```
    $.post(apiUrl,
            {
                userName: 'kamron',
                pwHash: sha256_digest('password')

            },
            function (data, status) {
                try {
                    alert(data, status);
                } catch (e) {
                    alert("System error, please try again.");
                };
            });
```

and

```
$.getJSON(apiUrl)
    .done(function (data) {
        // On success, 'data' contains a list of products.
        $.each(data, function (key, item) {
            // Add a list item for the product.
            alert(key + ':' + item);
        });
    });
```

I would appreciate anything and everything. I've been staring at this for over a day now trying to figure out what my problem is....

Any extra info that would help in helping me please ask for it, I tried to post everything relevant.

Thanks alot everyone :)

Comment: Put you `API Default` route before the `Default` route

Comment: Ok, did that, but still getting 404's on both the GET and the POST

Comment: Try `var apiUrl = "/api/LogIn";`

Comment: No luck :/ I appreciate the help. When defining a new ApiController in an MVC project, is there anywhere I need to do anything? I didn't see anything in the Web.config that seemed relevant

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read you code carefully enough - [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18420878/asp-net-mvc-4-apicontroller-and-normal-controller-routes) may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to have an action on the controller accepting a POST.  Also, the $.getJSON call doesn't have any arguments attached to it and you typically wouldn't want to pass credentials via a GET request for security reasons.

Posting multiple arguments to a WebApi is best achieved by creating a model representing the parameters, i.e,

```
 public class LogonRequest
 {
      public string Username { get; set; }
      public string Password { get; set; }
 }
```

and then accepting the model as shown below:

```
 // POST api/values
 public string Post([FromBody]LogonRequest creds)                          
 {
      //auth code...
 }
```

A good example of setting up both the jQuery call and the POST action can be found here:
[How to pass json POST data to Web API method as object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226169/how-to-pass-json-post-data-to-web-api-method-as-object)

Also, Fiddler can be a great help with these issues if you're not already using it.

Comment: The linked question above in the comments of my OQ, and this answer right here lead to me solving my issue :D